# Adjoint of Complex Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, adjoint-operators

Assume A is a matrix with complex entries. Prove that all diagonal elements of
the matrix (A*)A are real where A* is the adjoint of A.

Where do I start here?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Write the multiplication explicitly and the answer will just appear. More than just real, they will be non-negative numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$ have matrix elements $(A_{ij})$ where $i$ denotes row position and $j$ denotes column position. Then we have that the adjoint $A^* \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times m}$ has elements $(\bar A_{ji})$, with $\bar A_{ji}$ denoting the complex conjugate of $A_{ji}$, and $i$ again denoting row position and $j$ column position.

So from the definition of matrix multiplication, we have the formula for a matrix element $x_{ij}$ of $A^*A$:

> $$x_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^m \bar A_{ki} A_{kj}$$

When we calculate a diagonal element $x_{ii}$ with this formula, we obtain

> $$x_{ii} = \sum_{k=1}^m \bar A_{ki} A_{ki} = \sum_{k=1}^m |A_{ki}|^2$$

Comment: Thanks!! What makes the last part true?  The adjoint is a very new concept for me and I don't fully understand it yet.

Comment: Up voted. But in view of the OP's comment above, perhaps you want to use complex conjugation directly instead of $^*$ when you're applying it to a scalar.

Comment: @GitGud I've edited the notation of the complex conjugate to reflect your concern.

Comment: @JoshuaMundinger sir in adjoint of complex matrix, why it will be $\bar {A_{ji}} $ in (i,j) position. My doubt is why conjugate comes instead of only $A_{ji}$. Pls reply. I am learning matrix theory and reading some solutions to good problems